# Connection timedout uwsgi / unable to connect to node

Tags: uwsgi

We're having some issues with uwsgi behind a loadbalancer, logs are full or messages like below.
I'm new to nginx/uwsgi and stuff so I have no idea where to look at.

```
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (1 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http key: app.example.com client_addr: 10.133.223.217 client_port: 54217] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 646]
```

And also these format:

```
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
Wed Oct  5 07:24:42 2016 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:55792" (fd: 3) full !!! (257/256) ***
Wed Oct  5 07:24:44 2016 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:55792" (fd: 3) full !!! (257/256) ***
```

and also:

```
connect_to_tcp()/socket(): Too many open files [core/socket.c line 462]
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:55792" (0 retries): Connection timed out
connect_to_tcp()/socket(): Too many open files [core/socket.c line 462]
connect_to_tcp()/socket(): Too many open files [core/socket.c line 462]
```

There are 4 servers with 1gb ram and 1 core getting this events. (hosted on digital ocean).

If this helps:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max -> 1048576

ulimit -n 32768

net.core.somaxconn = 65000
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have too many open connections. `full !!! (257/256) ***` What happens when you restart uwsgi/nginx?

Comment: immediately after restart I still got it:  uWSGI listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:3414" (fd: 3) full !!! (257/256) ***

Comment: I increased the listen queue to 512 and get it full again.

Comment: How many uwsgi processes are you spawning?

Comment: 2 processes and 2 threads.

Comment: A bit stumped. I'm assuming it's not an application issue but uWSGI playing up, judging by what you said I don't see why it'd get backlogged with connections so much. Could you edit your answer and add your uWSGI/nginx config?

Comment: @AlexandruRada Could you add your uwsgi and nginx config to question?